Neovim vim.g.ftplugin_sql_omni_key = 0 not working
I am trying to edit an sql file in neovim. However the ftplugin/sql.vim (which I cant even find) sets some keybindings that start with <C-c> which is my <ESC> key.
I want searched the internet and the help page and found a "solution": Setting
vim.g.ftplugin_sql_omni_key to 1. This however does not work for me (and apparently also not for others: https://www.reddit.com/r/neovim/comments/x2nc8o/cant_disable_sql_omni_complete_in_neovim_072/)
I also found the option to change <C-c> to something like <leader>sql. This did also not work...
I tried to manually unmap them within an autocmd, this does not work because "no mapping <C-c>c found". Which is a mystery to me too.
Is there any way i can disable these keybindings or change them to something else? Is this a bug that I should report?
Thank you.

Do you still have something open in your question? How can we help you further? Otherwise maybe could you accept one of the answers using the v button next to the arrow voting buttons. It allow the question to rest :-)

Disable the mapping
I would define the g:omni_sql_no_default_maps variable:
let g:omni_sql_no_default_maps=1

More information with :help sql-completion-customization
The general help about the builtin sql filetype can be accessed with :help ft_sql.txt.
Use another key
If you want to keep the completion mapping but not using Ctrl c you could also define g:ftplugin_sql_omni_key to another valid key. e.g.:
let g:ftplugin_sql_omni_key = <C-s>

Unmap
These mapping are buffer mapping. If you want to selectively unmap them you have to put unmap code in a ./config/nvim/after/ftplugin/sql.vim file:
unmap <buffer> <C-c>a
unmap <buffer> <C-c>k
unmap <buffer> <C-c>f
unmap <buffer> <C-c>o
unmap <buffer> <C-c>T
...

